# Is there any way to make OS X more tolerant of momentary USB disconnects?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt, dock

My MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019) is connected to a Thunderbolt 3 dock which has external monitors and, most crucially, a USB3 Time Machine drive on it.

If I so much as lightly touch the Thunderbolt cable, the dock and all attached devices disconnect. The biggest concern is the unsafe un-mounting of the hard drive, but losing my monitors, keyboard and microphone is also annoying.

Is there any setting which would make OS X more tolerant in momentary (less than 2 second) Thunderbold disconnects? I expect not... in which case, are there any hardware changes which can make a Thunderbolt connection less flakey? (It's an Apple thunderbolt cable, but a third party dock)

Comment: I would say that the problem lies with the Dock, not the Mac. If it is disconnecting things at the slightest touch, then something is wrong. Luckily, it's cheaper to replace the Dock than the Mac.

Comment: I agree, but it’s specifically the cable where it connects to the mac which is so problematic. Maybe it’s the cable itself, but this is the third one I have tried (and different ports too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there’s no such setting. That sort of thing is not possible to make happen in software in the operating system.

I would advise you to use cables and docks that allows you to physically lock the cable, so that you do not accidentally unplug it. Some plugs can be locked with screws to the dock, or have various “twist-to-lock” mechanism to ensure a reliable connection.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this was the answer, but I figured I would check